Get vertical alignement for superscripted and non-superscripted subscripts
Writing the following code \frame{$a_{B^-} + a_{B}$} produces:

wherein the bottom of the B letters are not aligned. I can solve this issue by adding \usepackage{subdepth} and \frame{$a_{B^-} + a_{B\vphantom{B^-}}$} which produces:

however this is lowering both of the B (compare closely first and second images), the position of the minus sign also changes, and this is lowering the right B.
Is there a way to raise the left B^- instead so that it is at the same level as the B?
My concern is primarily that I have many x_Y in my equations, and I would like to only modify the a_{B^-} part of my code in order to rise the B^- and not all the instances of x_Y to lower the Y.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I found several related topics but not quite this one:

Subscript vertical position dependent on presence of superscript - how to change?
Persistent subscript placement with or without superscript
Vertical positioning of superscripts with different heights (mathstrut solution similar to my vphantom attempt)


Note: I did not described them for the sake of conciseness, but the inclusion of amsmath and / or subdepth gives a variety of in-between results (none of them being perfectly aligned).

The lowering is due to the minus sign having the same bounding box as the plus sign.
According to the rules explained in Appendix G of the TeXbook, when a subscript is too high (there's a threshold for deciding when) it is lowered.
You need to smash the minus sign:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\showbb}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}%
  \fbox{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\showbb{$a_{B^-} + a_{B}$} \showbb{$a_{B^{\smash{-}}} + a_{B}$}

\end{document}


I replaced your \frame with a different method that keeps the baseline.
Of course you want to define a command for such symbol.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\spminus}{^{\smash{-}}}

\begin{document}

$a_{B\spminus} + a_{B}$

\end{document}


